# how to implement laravel validation unique in UpdateRequest custom?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

I have a unique rule in file UpdateAnimeRequest, and I want to implement a unique rule like this:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

The problem is if I want to update without changing the title then the unique error appears, how can I prevent this error from appearing when the user doesn't want to change the title input field?

Here is the contents of my custom request file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Rules\ValidGenre;
use App\Rules\ValidWord;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class UpdateAnimeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|unique:animes,title|max:25',
            'genres' => [
                'required', new ValidGenre(), new ValidWord()
            ],
            'status' => 'nullable|regex:/1/',
            'link' => 'nullable|url',
            'motivasi' => 'nullable|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]*$/',
        ];
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return Gate::allows('anime_access');
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to implement ignore self in my custom request?

Comment: why do you want ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first if you want to ignore self then you must have anime_id to know if this have self or not
then rule can be

```
'title' => ['required', "max:25", Rule::unique('animes', 'title')->ignore($this->anime->id, 'id')],
```

Comment: i try dd $this->anime and the output null?

Comment: no that just an example, it mean your UpdateAnimeRequest need to know if this anime is exist or not (replace `$this->anime->id` with your current anime id)